# Como verificar se um checkbox esta checado com jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ola, estou tentando fazer uma operação em JS caso um checkbox esteja checado, porem não estou obtendo sucesso. Segue o código:

```
  $('#btn-proximo').click(function(e){
            if($('#in_acesso').is('checked')){

            $('#div_valida :input').each(function(){
              if(this.value == "" || this.value == " "){
                e.preventDefault();
                 this.focus();

            } 
          if($('#password').val() != $('#password_confirmation').val()){
            $('#dados_gerais').preventDefault();
            $('#erroSenha').show('fade');
            setTimeout(function(){
              $('#erroSenha').hide('fade');
            },6000);
            $('#password').focus();

          }

        })
        }
        })
```

Comment: Coloque o `:` antes do checked, assim `.is(':checked')`

Comment: mude a linha if($('#in_acesso').is('checked')){ para if($('#in_acesso').is(':checked')){
Faltou só o ":" antes do "checked"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**JQUERY – VERIFICANDO UM CHECKBOX COM IS(‘:CHECKED’)**

A primeira forma de se fazer esta verificação é usando a função is() do jQuery. Ela verifica se o argumento, ou conjunto de argumentos que você declarou satisfazem a condição determinada. Caso positivo, ela retorna “verdadeiro”. Caso negativo, retorna “falso”.

Para usar o is(), primeiro precisamos escolher o elemento e depois fazer a verificação usando o seletor `:checked` , que funciona com checkboxes, entre outros.

Você usou simplesmente `checked` sem `:` (dois pontos)

**Veja**

```js
$('#btn-proximo').click(function(e){
     if($('#in_acesso').is('checked')){
          console.log("primeiro codigo");   
     }

     if($('#in_acesso').is(':checked')){
          console.log("segundo codigo");
     }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="btn-proximo">proximo</button>

<input type="checkbox" id="in_acesso">
```

Answer (score 3):

O Jquery possui o seletor `:checked`, e com a ajuda do `length` você consegue obter o valor 1 quando o objeto for selecionado. Desta forma, você consegue "checkar" um ou mais checkbox. Enquanto o checkbox não for selecionado, ele possui valor 0, logo você pode desenvolver sua lógica a partir desta funcionalidade. Espero que ajude. Segue o código de exemplo:

```js
$('#check').on('click', function(){
 var checkbox = $('#check:checked').length;
  console.log(checkbox);
  
  if(checkbox === 1)
  {
    alert('Parabéns! \o/');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
  </body>
</html>
```